# Ubuntu server stops working everyday overnight

Tags: 20.04, ssh

Everyday, my ubuntu server stops responding (I think overnight) and I have to restart it. I cant even SSH on. These are the server logs for the morning (before restart):

```
Jul 01 23:54:37 hcah sshd[4085]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 103.131.52.4 port 44684: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:54:40 hcah sshd[4087]: Received disconnect from 103.131.52.4 port 47265:11: disconnected by user [preauth]
Jul 01 23:54:40 hcah sshd[4087]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 103.131.52.4 port 47265 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:54:42 hcah sshd[4089]: Invalid user admin from 103.131.52.4 port 48297
Jul 01 23:54:43 hcah sshd[4089]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user admin from 103.131.52.4 port 48297 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:54:43 hcah sshd[4089]: Disconnecting invalid user admin 103.131.52.4 port 48297: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:54:45 hcah sshd[4091]: Invalid user admin from 103.131.52.4 port 49361
Jul 01 23:54:47 hcah sshd[4091]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user admin from 103.131.52.4 port 49361 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:54:47 hcah sshd[4091]: Disconnecting invalid user admin 103.131.52.4 port 49361: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:54:49 hcah sshd[4093]: Invalid user admin from 103.131.52.4 port 50484
Jul 01 23:54:49 hcah sshd[4093]: Received disconnect from 103.131.52.4 port 50484:11: disconnected by user [preauth]
Jul 01 23:54:49 hcah sshd[4093]: Disconnected from invalid user admin 103.131.52.4 port 50484 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:54:51 hcah sshd[4095]: Invalid user oracle from 103.131.52.4 port 51352
Jul 01 23:54:52 hcah sshd[4095]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user oracle from 103.131.52.4 port 51352 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:54:52 hcah sshd[4095]: Disconnecting invalid user oracle 103.131.52.4 port 51352: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:54:54 hcah sshd[4097]: Invalid user oracle from 103.131.52.4 port 52492
Jul 01 23:54:56 hcah sshd[4097]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user oracle from 103.131.52.4 port 52492 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:54:56 hcah sshd[4097]: Disconnecting invalid user oracle 103.131.52.4 port 52492: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:54:58 hcah sshd[4099]: Invalid user oracle from 103.131.52.4 port 53542
Jul 01 23:54:58 hcah sshd[4099]: Received disconnect from 103.131.52.4 port 53542:11: disconnected by user [preauth]
Jul 01 23:54:58 hcah sshd[4099]: Disconnected from invalid user oracle 103.131.52.4 port 53542 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:00 hcah sshd[4101]: Invalid user usuario from 103.131.52.4 port 54279
Jul 01 23:55:01 hcah sshd[4101]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user usuario from 103.131.52.4 port 54279 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:01 hcah sshd[4101]: Disconnecting invalid user usuario 103.131.52.4 port 54279: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:03 hcah sshd[4103]: Invalid user usuario from 103.131.52.4 port 55590
Jul 01 23:55:05 hcah sshd[4103]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user usuario from 103.131.52.4 port 55590 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:05 hcah sshd[4103]: Disconnecting invalid user usuario 103.131.52.4 port 55590: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:07 hcah sshd[4105]: Invalid user usuario from 103.131.52.4 port 56773
Jul 01 23:55:07 hcah sshd[4105]: Received disconnect from 103.131.52.4 port 56773:11: disconnected by user [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:07 hcah sshd[4105]: Disconnected from invalid user usuario 103.131.52.4 port 56773 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:07 hcah sshd[4107]: Unable to negotiate with 209.141.43.233 port 36274: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:09 hcah sshd[4109]: Invalid user test from 103.131.52.4 port 57479
Jul 01 23:55:10 hcah sshd[4109]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user test from 103.131.52.4 port 57479 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:10 hcah sshd[4109]: Disconnecting invalid user test 103.131.52.4 port 57479: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:12 hcah sshd[4111]: Invalid user test from 103.131.52.4 port 58644
Jul 01 23:55:14 hcah sshd[4111]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user test from 103.131.52.4 port 58644 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:14 hcah sshd[4111]: Disconnecting invalid user test 103.131.52.4 port 58644: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:15 hcah kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens192 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:0b:82:6d:00:50:56:af:33:4a:08:00 SRC=74.120.14.27 DST=77.68.84.223 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=41 ID=17691 PROTO=TCP SPT=23868 DPT=993 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Jul 01 23:55:16 hcah sshd[4113]: Invalid user test from 103.131.52.4 port 59839
Jul 01 23:55:16 hcah sshd[4113]: Received disconnect from 103.131.52.4 port 59839:11: disconnected by user [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:16 hcah sshd[4113]: Disconnected from invalid user test 103.131.52.4 port 59839 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:18 hcah sshd[4115]: Invalid user user from 103.131.52.4 port 60589
Jul 01 23:55:19 hcah sshd[4115]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user user from 103.131.52.4 port 60589 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:19 hcah sshd[4115]: Disconnecting invalid user user 103.131.52.4 port 60589: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:21 hcah sshd[4117]: Invalid user user from 103.131.52.4 port 61856
Jul 01 23:55:23 hcah sshd[4117]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user user from 103.131.52.4 port 61856 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:23 hcah sshd[4117]: Disconnecting invalid user user 103.131.52.4 port 61856: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:25 hcah sshd[4119]: Invalid user user from 103.131.52.4 port 63031
Jul 01 23:55:25 hcah sshd[4119]: Received disconnect from 103.131.52.4 port 63031:11: disconnected by user [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:25 hcah sshd[4119]: Disconnected from invalid user user 103.131.52.4 port 63031 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:27 hcah sshd[4121]: Invalid user ftpuser from 103.131.52.4 port 63746
Jul 01 23:55:29 hcah sshd[4121]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user ftpuser from 103.131.52.4 port 63746 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:29 hcah sshd[4121]: Disconnecting invalid user ftpuser 103.131.52.4 port 63746: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:30 hcah sshd[4124]: Invalid user ftpuser from 103.131.52.4 port 65073
Jul 01 23:55:32 hcah sshd[4124]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user ftpuser from 103.131.52.4 port 65073 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:32 hcah sshd[4124]: Disconnecting invalid user ftpuser 103.131.52.4 port 65073: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:34 hcah sshd[4126]: Invalid user ftpuser from 103.131.52.4 port 10632
Jul 01 23:55:34 hcah sshd[4126]: Received disconnect from 103.131.52.4 port 10632:11: disconnected by user [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:34 hcah sshd[4126]: Disconnected from invalid user ftpuser 103.131.52.4 port 10632 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:36 hcah sshd[4128]: Invalid user test1 from 103.131.52.4 port 11392
Jul 01 23:55:37 hcah sshd[4128]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user test1 from 103.131.52.4 port 11392 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:37 hcah sshd[4128]: Disconnecting invalid user test1 103.131.52.4 port 11392: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:39 hcah sshd[4130]: Invalid user test1 from 103.131.52.4 port 12590
Jul 01 23:55:41 hcah sshd[4130]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user test1 from 103.131.52.4 port 12590 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:41 hcah sshd[4130]: Disconnecting invalid user test1 103.131.52.4 port 12590: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:43 hcah sshd[4132]: Invalid user test1 from 103.131.52.4 port 13858
Jul 01 23:55:43 hcah sshd[4132]: Received disconnect from 103.131.52.4 port 13858:11: disconnected by user [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:43 hcah sshd[4132]: Disconnected from invalid user test1 103.131.52.4 port 13858 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:45 hcah sshd[4134]: Invalid user test2 from 103.131.52.4 port 14603
Jul 01 23:55:46 hcah sshd[4134]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user test2 from 103.131.52.4 port 14603 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:46 hcah sshd[4134]: Disconnecting invalid user test2 103.131.52.4 port 14603: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:48 hcah sshd[4136]: Invalid user test2 from 103.131.52.4 port 15779
Jul 01 23:55:50 hcah sshd[4136]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user test2 from 103.131.52.4 port 15779 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:50 hcah sshd[4136]: Disconnecting invalid user test2 103.131.52.4 port 15779: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:52 hcah sshd[4138]: Invalid user test2 from 103.131.52.4 port 17049
Jul 01 23:55:53 hcah sshd[4138]: Received disconnect from 103.131.52.4 port 17049:11: disconnected by user [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:53 hcah sshd[4138]: Disconnected from invalid user test2 103.131.52.4 port 17049 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:54 hcah sshd[4140]: Invalid user contador from 103.131.52.4 port 17772
Jul 01 23:55:55 hcah sshd[4140]: Received disconnect from 103.131.52.4 port 17772:11: disconnected by user [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:55 hcah sshd[4140]: Disconnected from invalid user contador 103.131.52.4 port 17772 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:56 hcah sshd[4142]: Invalid user duni from 103.131.52.4 port 18533
Jul 01 23:55:57 hcah sshd[4142]: Received disconnect from 103.131.52.4 port 18533:11: disconnected by user [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:57 hcah sshd[4142]: Disconnected from invalid user duni 103.131.52.4 port 18533 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:58 hcah sshd[4144]: Invalid user pi from 103.131.52.4 port 19299
Jul 01 23:55:59 hcah sshd[4144]: Received disconnect from 103.131.52.4 port 19299:11: disconnected by user [preauth]
Jul 01 23:55:59 hcah sshd[4144]: Disconnected from invalid user pi 103.131.52.4 port 19299 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:56:01 hcah sshd[4146]: Invalid user baikal from 103.131.52.4 port 20072
Jul 01 23:56:01 hcah sshd[4146]: Received disconnect from 103.131.52.4 port 20072:11: disconnected by user [preauth]
Jul 01 23:56:01 hcah sshd[4146]: Disconnected from invalid user baikal 103.131.52.4 port 20072 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:57:00 hcah sshd[4148]: Unable to negotiate with 209.141.43.233 port 37464: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:58:33 hcah sshd[4150]: Unable to negotiate with 209.141.43.233 port 38654: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Jul 01 23:59:52 hcah sshd[4152]: Received disconnect from 111.67.203.141 port 47604:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jul 01 23:59:52 hcah sshd[4152]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 111.67.203.141 port 47604 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:00:00 hcah sshd[4154]: Unable to negotiate with 209.141.43.233 port 39844: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:00:00 hcah systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
Jul 02 00:00:00 hcah systemd[1]: Starting Daily man-db regeneration...
Jul 02 00:00:00 hcah systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Jul 02 00:00:00 hcah systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Jul 02 00:00:00 hcah rsyslogd[938]: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2001.0" x-pid="938" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Jul 02 00:00:00 hcah systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Succeeded.
Jul 02 00:00:00 hcah systemd[1]: Finished Rotate log files.
Jul 02 00:00:01 hcah systemd[1]: man-db.service: Succeeded.
Jul 02 00:00:01 hcah systemd[1]: Finished Daily man-db regeneration.
Jul 02 00:01:39 hcah sshd[4279]: Unable to negotiate with 209.141.43.233 port 41034: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:02:03 hcah sshd[4281]: Received disconnect from 65.24.66.132 port 44872:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jul 02 00:02:03 hcah sshd[4281]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 65.24.66.132 port 44872 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:03:18 hcah sshd[4283]: Unable to negotiate with 209.141.43.233 port 42222: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:05:01 hcah sshd[4285]: Unable to negotiate with 209.141.43.233 port 43420: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:06:45 hcah sshd[4288]: Unable to negotiate with 209.141.43.233 port 44604: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:08:23 hcah sshd[4290]: Unable to negotiate with 209.141.43.233 port 45796: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:08:24 hcah sshd[4292]: Received disconnect from 95.182.139.119 port 38456:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jul 02 00:08:24 hcah sshd[4292]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 95.182.139.119 port 38456 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:10:07 hcah sshd[4294]: Unable to negotiate with 209.141.43.233 port 46984: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:10:08 hcah kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens192 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:0b:82:6d:00:50:56:af:33:4a:08:00 SRC=88.9.119.217 DST=77.68.84.223 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=51207 DPT=8000 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Jul 02 00:10:59 hcah sshd[4296]: Received disconnect from 49.234.43.127 port 38408:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jul 02 00:10:59 hcah sshd[4296]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 49.234.43.127 port 38408 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:11:53 hcah sshd[4299]: Unable to negotiate with 209.141.43.233 port 48172: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:13:13 hcah sshd[4301]: Invalid user  from 65.49.20.66 port 41088
Jul 02 00:13:17 hcah sshd[4301]: Connection closed by invalid user  65.49.20.66 port 41088 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:13:38 hcah sshd[4305]: Unable to negotiate with 209.141.43.233 port 49364: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:13:40 hcah sshd[4303]: Connection closed by 192.241.215.97 port 55686 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:14:59 hcah sshd[4307]: Received disconnect from 210.245.92.136 port 54888:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jul 02 00:14:59 hcah sshd[4307]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 210.245.92.136 port 54888 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:15:19 hcah sshd[4309]: Unable to negotiate with 209.141.43.233 port 50552: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:15:22 hcah kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens192 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:0b:82:6d:00:50:56:af:33:4a:08:00 SRC=74.120.14.16 DST=77.68.84.223 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=41 ID=5856 PROTO=TCP SPT=29266 DPT=587 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Jul 02 00:15:41 hcah sshd[4311]: Received disconnect from 49.51.180.246 port 42242:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jul 02 00:15:41 hcah sshd[4311]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 49.51.180.246 port 42242 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:17:01 hcah CRON[4315]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 02 00:17:01 hcah CRON[4316]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 02 00:17:01 hcah CRON[4315]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 02 00:19:44 hcah sshd[4318]: Received disconnect from 121.5.243.95 port 57770:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jul 02 00:19:44 hcah sshd[4318]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 121.5.243.95 port 57770 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:26:01 hcah sshd[4322]: Received disconnect from 142.93.8.164 port 40802:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jul 02 00:26:01 hcah sshd[4322]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 142.93.8.164 port 40802 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:27:03 hcah sshd[4324]: Received disconnect from 185.111.88.212 port 53384:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jul 02 00:27:03 hcah sshd[4324]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 185.111.88.212 port 53384 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:29:12 hcah sshd[4326]: Received disconnect from 159.75.67.197 port 54718:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jul 02 00:29:12 hcah sshd[4326]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 159.75.67.197 port 54718 [preauth]
Jul 02 00:31:35 hcah systemd-timesyncd[806]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
Jul 02 01:17:01 hcah CRON[4334]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 02 01:17:01 hcah CRON[4335]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 02 01:17:01 hcah CRON[4334]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 02 02:17:01 hcah CRON[4344]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 02 02:17:01 hcah CRON[4345]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 02 02:17:01 hcah CRON[4344]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 02 02:33:49 hcah systemd[1]: Starting Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
Jul 02 02:33:50 hcah dbus-daemon[923]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.fwupd' unit='fwupd.service' requested by ':1.36' (uid=62803 pid=4350 comm="/usr/bin/fwupdmgr refresh --no-metadata-check " label="unconfined")
Jul 02 02:33:50 hcah systemd[1]: Starting Firmware update daemon...
Jul 02 02:33:50 hcah dbus-daemon[923]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
Jul 02 02:33:50 hcah systemd[1]: Started Firmware update daemon.
Jul 02 02:33:50 hcah systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Succeeded.
Jul 02 02:33:50 hcah systemd[1]: Finished Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Jul 02 03:10:01 hcah CRON[4383]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 02 03:10:01 hcah CRON[4384]: (root) CMD (test -e /run/systemd/system || SERVICE_MODE=1 /sbin/e2scrub_all -A -r)
Jul 02 03:10:01 hcah CRON[4383]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 02 03:17:01 hcah CRON[4386]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 02 03:17:01 hcah CRON[4387]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 02 03:17:01 hcah CRON[4386]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 02 03:17:08 hcah snapd[942]: autorefresh.go:501: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 03:17:08 hcah snapd[942]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 03:42:08 hcah snapd[942]: autorefresh.go:501: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 03:42:08 hcah snapd[942]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 04:02:08 hcah snapd[942]: autorefresh.go:501: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 04:02:08 hcah snapd[942]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 04:17:01 hcah CRON[4397]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 02 04:17:01 hcah CRON[4398]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 02 04:17:01 hcah CRON[4397]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 02 04:27:08 hcah snapd[942]: autorefresh.go:501: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 04:27:08 hcah snapd[942]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 04:33:50 hcah systemd[1]: fwupd.service: Succeeded.
Jul 02 04:47:08 hcah snapd[942]: autorefresh.go:501: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 04:47:08 hcah snapd[942]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 05:12:08 hcah snapd[942]: autorefresh.go:501: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 05:12:08 hcah snapd[942]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 05:17:01 hcah CRON[4432]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 02 05:17:01 hcah CRON[4433]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 02 05:17:01 hcah CRON[4432]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 02 05:32:08 hcah snapd[942]: autorefresh.go:501: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 05:32:08 hcah snapd[942]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 05:57:08 hcah snapd[942]: autorefresh.go:501: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 05:57:08 hcah snapd[942]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 06:17:01 hcah CRON[4444]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 02 06:17:01 hcah CRON[4445]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 02 06:17:01 hcah CRON[4444]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 02 06:22:08 hcah snapd[942]: autorefresh.go:501: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 06:22:08 hcah snapd[942]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 06:25:01 hcah CRON[4449]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 02 06:25:01 hcah CRON[4450]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Jul 02 06:25:01 hcah CRON[4449]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 02 06:41:22 hcah systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Jul 02 06:41:52 hcah systemd-networkd-wait-online[4520]: Event loop failed: Connection timed out
Jul 02 06:41:52 hcah apt-helper[4510]: E: Sub-process /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online returned an error code (1)
Jul 02 06:41:54 hcah systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Succeeded.
Jul 02 06:41:54 hcah systemd[1]: Finished Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Jul 02 06:42:08 hcah snapd[942]: autorefresh.go:501: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 06:42:08 hcah snapd[942]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 07:03:49 hcah systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
Jul 02 07:04:20 hcah systemd-networkd-wait-online[4632]: Event loop failed: Connection timed out
Jul 02 07:04:20 hcah apt-helper[4620]: E: Sub-process /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online returned an error code (1)
Jul 02 07:04:22 hcah systemd[1]: apt-daily.service: Succeeded.
Jul 02 07:04:22 hcah systemd[1]: Finished Daily apt download activities.
Jul 02 07:07:08 hcah snapd[942]: autorefresh.go:501: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 07:07:08 hcah snapd[942]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 07:17:01 hcah CRON[4722]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 02 07:17:01 hcah CRON[4723]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 02 07:17:01 hcah CRON[4722]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 02 07:28:22 hcah systemd[1]: Starting Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
Jul 02 07:28:22 hcah dbus-daemon[923]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.fwupd' unit='fwupd.service' requested by ':1.40' (uid=62803 pid=4726 comm="/usr/bin/fwupdmgr refresh --no-metadata-check " label="unconfined")
Jul 02 07:28:22 hcah systemd[1]: Starting Firmware update daemon...
Jul 02 07:28:22 hcah dbus-daemon[923]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
Jul 02 07:28:22 hcah systemd[1]: Started Firmware update daemon.
Jul 02 07:28:22 hcah systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Succeeded.
Jul 02 07:28:22 hcah systemd[1]: Finished Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Jul 02 07:32:08 hcah snapd[942]: autorefresh.go:501: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 07:32:08 hcah snapd[942]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 07:52:08 hcah snapd[942]: autorefresh.go:501: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 02 07:52:08 hcah snapd[942]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I am terrible with logs but it looks like by 00:31 it cant access the network. It looks like people are trying to access my server? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @user535733 : I do not see a successful login, I only see failed attempts which is pretty normal for any externally enabled ssh. Can you give a specific time reference? OP: your network seems to go down at about 00:30, as you already mentioned. Don't know why.

Comment: Hi @Doug Smythies, Im not sure when the network goes down. Just before this log, I successfully accessed the server and there were no issues. So it must happen after 2300 but I cant see why in the logs.

Comment: The network is working at 00:29:12 and not working at 00:31:35. Search any other logs in this time area.

Comment: @DougSmythies you are correct. Oops, thanks for spotting that.

Comment: I have checked syslogs and the journalctl for that service but I cannot see any particular reason why the network goes down.

Comment: Try some things before you re-boot tomorrow morning. Try: `sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd`. And try just re-starting the network, instead of re-boot: `sudo systemctl re-start systemd-networkd` (I think, I didn't test it.)

Comment: @Doug Smythies I wish I could but I cant even SSH on, I just have to use my hosting providers web panel to restart it!

Comment: Oh. I thought it was perhaps a local computer. Hopefully someone will chime in with help. Otherwise. maybe get a cron job to run every hour doing `sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd` to a log file. There is likely a way to get more information logged, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Interestingly, I am used to being able to hot plug ethernet cables at my switch, but when I did so yesterday my computer crashed with a similar `systemd-timesyncd[806]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.` message.

Comment: Nope still ongoing :( Will update here if I find the solution.

Comment: @Saif still nothing ? I get exactly the same problem

Comment: @IgorBeaufils No unfortunately not. I had to wipe the server and start again.

Comment: @Saif ok that does not work for me sadly it keeps coming again and again.
still thanks for your response